# I use Emacs with Prelude and want to re/write git-autocommit-mode

Tags: emacs, emacs24, emacs-prelude

Where inside .emacs.d should I put the source code? How should I publish my changes? This is my first attempt at writing an Emacs mode. What are the current commendations?

### proggress

I'm not sure if I did it properly but I have added following to my

~/.emacs.d/personal/personal.el

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacs.d/vendor")
(require 'git-auto-commit-mode)
```

then I did 'git clone myrepo' in the vendor directory.

Comment: https://twitter.com/bbatsov/status/512317928881258496

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used Prelude myself, but it's got an
[init.el](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/blob/master/init.el),
which is probably where you should put a statement to load your code.

But if you're really at the point where you want to write your own
code, I'd recommend to either dump Prelude in favor of rolling your
own config, or completely understand how Prelude works and build on
top of that. Anything in the middle will result in much confusion.

Here's how I'd go about changing `git-autocommit-mode`:

1. visit melpa.org to lookup the source: https://github.com/ryuslash/git-auto-commit-mode
2. fork the source on github
3. clone the repo I just forked:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/abo-abo/git-auto-commit-mode.git
   ```
4. uninstall `git-auto-commit-mode` via package.el
5. install `use-package`
6. use this code to load your own `git-auto-commit-mode`:

   ```
   (use-package git-auto-commit-mode
     :load-path "~/git/git-auto-commit-mode")
   ```
7. if you make changes that you think are useful, open a pull request
   on github to merge in your changes into the source repo

Comment: Slowly, I'm getting there. I need to test it for a while before I do my first Emacs pull request.